# How to make jquery https calls and ignore ssl errors in uwp app

Tags: javascript, https, uwp, hybrid-mobile-app, uwp-xaml

I have to make https call in a javascript function I am calling through UWP app using ScriptNotify,

My Domain is for ex https://test.com/test/12

```
function testHttpsCall() {
  try {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://differentdomain.com/test/12",
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      },
      complete: function() {
        console.log("Comes here");
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

it is not coming to either of the code block inside request and as I can't debug hybrid app on mobile I am unable to find issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should almost never attempt to contact different server then the one you are hosting your app from. In those rare cases when this is neccesary the other server must explicitly allow your page to make requests by setting proper CORS headers.

Comment: @ Marcin Yes CORS is enabled on that server

Comment: Thats what I am not able to know

Comment: try to create an html file on your desktop and call this ajax in browser, I think the error can be the return type, if you're expecting a json, you'll get errors... I tried it some days ago too, so. in different domains, you get jsonp datatype, not json

Comment: if alert does not work do document.body.innerHTML = error.getMessae() lol

Comment: innerHTML will also not work as this is UWP right, ok then as Felipe suggested you should try it on desktop

Comment: @Marcin I tried it before does not help. It didnt came to any of the blocks

Comment: I dont know much about UWP but is jQuery suppose to work there?

Comment: @MarcinMalinowski Yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153715/discussion-between-john-and-marcin-malinowski).

Comment: did you guys find a solution for this? I am facing the same problem